# Unable to run ios simulator with react native cli

Tags: react-native

Screenshot of `npx react-native doctor`:
[image]

As you can see, the iOS is all green ticks. I `npm start` in a terminal tab to run react native metro server. I then open another terminal and `npm run ios` Yes, the simulator opens straight away, but then I get a long error: https://pastebin.com/6bFTMDTr

I `cd ios` then `pod install` and got this:
[image]

Anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing the pod dependency manually?

> $ cd iOS && pod install

upd.
Looks like you haven't installed Ruby

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
brew install ruby
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile
```

after that install a watchman depend

```
$ brew update
$ brew install watchman
```

upd2.

```
1) brew reinstall cocoapods
```

(error message will come up regarding linking)

```
2) brew link --overwrite cocoapods
```

(to fix the link)

Comment: I did, when I ruby -v I have 2.7.5 installed. Prior to this error I spent 5 days trying to react-native init. But its all good now. Now this ios simulator is my only issue. Btw, I installed ruby using chruby. It was what fixed my 5 day old issue